# web service references

Tags: c#, web-services, app-config

I have an solution, that has many projects within it.  Three of the projects that reside within the main solution have web service calls within them.  These web service projects (.dlls) go out, grab some data, and return (normal operation).  They then process the data, and present it to the main application (another project within the solution).

Each project has its own app.config file that sets the references to the locations of the exposed web services, and the references are set to dynamic.

I do not distribute the .config files for the projects, only the main project within the solution.

My question, after long description is this....

Can the other projects see and use the app.config of the main application?

What i would like to do is use a single app.config, and have ALL the projects reference that ONE app.config file to get the locations of the exposed web services.

Can this be accomplished?

Side question....  if i do not distribute the app.config dlls for the other projects in the solution, how do they know know the location of the exposed web services?

Third side question - if i distribute the other projects app.config with the solution, will the projects reference the attached app.config dll, or will they ignore it, and use the hard coded (at build time)  references?

thank you

Comment: If the service project dlls are loaded into main app's domain, they should 'see' references to services defined in main app's app.config, so you need to define references only once in main application's config file. Did you try to do this?

Comment: no - i have not included the location of the other projects web service locations in the main projects app.config

Answer (score 1):

`Can the other projects see and use the app.config of the main application`

Yes. Generally speaking, if the main project references the other projects, which I assume it must, then when you build and deploy the main project, the app.config settings specified in that project's app.config file, will be used for the config references in the other projects.

`if i do not distribute the app.config dlls for the other projects in the solution, how do they know know the location of the exposed web services?`

Because you've specified them in the app.config of the main project.

`if i distribute the other projects app.config with the solution, will the projects reference the attached app.config dll, or will they ignore it, and use the hard coded (at build time) references?`

They should use the settings specified in the app.config, at runtime.

Comment: the location of the web services are not included in the main app.config.... if i include them in the main app.config, will they be available to the other projects?

Comment: If a local app.config is not found, the assemblies will look for a configuration file in the appdomain.

Comment: @pithhelmet - if you include them in the main app.config, the other projects will pick them up, yes. As Elad said, they will look for a config file in the appdomain, which, if you have one (a config file)  on your main project, they will find, and use.